# Django SelectTimeWidget readonly

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Here is my django code,

```
class Fpool_Booked(forms.Form):

    From = forms.CharField(label = 'Departure Place',max_length = 30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}),error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter From where do you want to go'})

    To = forms.CharField(label = 'Destination Place',max_length = 30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}),error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter destination'})

    From_Time = forms.TimeField(label = 'Departure Time',widget = SelectTimeWidget(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'},twelve_hr = True))
```

as you can see i have made text field readly which works fine ,in the same way i wanna make SelectTimeWidget readonly i have tried `attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}` but does not work as expected. is there any way to fix this ?/

Comment: Why are you using a widget like that if you want it to be read only? just display a text widget

Comment: hmmm but i wanted to try in this method so thaat it does not affect my other css templates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SelectTimeWidget is a custom widget based on the SelectDateWidget. I don't think it supports 'readonly'. I've probably overdone the answer but I had a play and came up with the following which may help if you really want to do it...

[I dropped the SelectTimeWidget snippet into my code](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1202/) and changed the following lines

```
def __init__(self, attrs=None, hour_step=None, minute_step=None, second_step=None, twelve_hr=False):
```

to:

```
def __init__(self, attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}, hour_step=None, minute_step=None, second_step=None, twelve_hr=False):
```

and:

```
select_html = Select(choices=hour_choices).render(self.hour_field % name, hour_val, local_attrs)
select_html = Select(choices=minute_choices).render(self.minute_field % name, minute_val, local_attrs)
select_html = Select(choices=second_choices).render(self.second_field % name, second_val, local_attrs)
```

To:

```
select_html = TextInput().render(self.hour_field % name, hour_val, local_attrs)
select_html = TextInput().render(self.minute_field % name, minute_val, local_attrs)
select_html = TextInput().render(self.second_field % name, second_val, local_attrs)
```

I used the following form style when I want to post values into form fields and be more dynamic, able to access values within the form and change the form on the fly.

```
class time_form(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(time_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['From'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'onchange':'this.form.submit()'}))
        self.fields['To'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'onchange':'this.form.submit()'}))
        self.fields['From_Time'] = forms.TimeField(widget = SelectTimeWidget())
```

In the view I set the values to see how it looked:

```
form = time_form({'From_Time':'12:34:56 P.M.',})
```

Note I left in attrs={'onchange':'this.form.submit()'} for the fun of it in case you want to dynamically update the form when changes are made, (and to show where attr= goes), although I find this tends to work best with select widgets. In the form you can access the 'From' and 'To' values (e.g. var = args[0].get('To')) and update the 'From_Time' (args[0]['From_Time']= some function).

Secondly, the 'From_Time' widget is now just a glorified read only TextInput box that parses time formats so it seems like a complicated way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disable a select widget in my form and I used this code just to disable the field:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   self.fields['field_name'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

The select input field has no '*readonly*' attribute.